# Google App Engine Python - keep getting redirected from localhost:8000 to localhost:8000/instances

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a Google App Engine app working on Mac OS X and I'm getting a strange, hard-to-google problem. The first time I installed, it worked mostly okay except it wasn't interpreting some {% tags correctly. I tried giving it a more explicit path to Python in Preferences, which caused it to hang up on the yellow clock status.

Because of this, I reinstalled and left the path to python blank. But now when I open the server and go to localhost:8000, I get redirected to /instances. This was not happening before, and I'm completely stumped as to why.

localhost:8080 redirects to a weird login page that demands an authenticated email but no password and does not accept any emails.

Comment: localhost:8000 is the SDK's control-panel; your app runs on :8080. The 'weird login page' is how you simulate logging in with a google account while developing. By itself, it accepts *all* emails, so the issue is most likely in your code, or in your app.yaml config.